# Rails and jQuery: remove class after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I vahe view form, this form have:

`<%= link_to day, root_path(:day => day), :id => 'link', :class => 'active_link' %>`

This link reneder this form with day parameter and items on this form rendered with this parameter. I want that after clicking on this link, after re-rendering form - class 'active_link' removed. How can I make it?

P.S: this is link for item (day item from collection).

Answer (score 1):

This is a view logic problem, not a JavaScript/jQuery problem. You are using a normal link to change the day parameter and re-render the entire page. Based on the only line of code you are showing us, I'm guessing your view loops through a bunch of dates and prints a link out for each one. The problem is, you are assigning the `active_link` class to all of the day links in your view. "Fixing" this problem with jQuery in the browser after the page loads is the wrong approach; instead fix your view logic to only assign the `active_link` class to the one correct link (and ditch the non-unique 'link' ids).

In your controller:

```
@active_day = params[:day]
```

In your view:

```
<% days.each do |day| %>
  <%= link_to day, root_path(:day => day), :class => (day == @active_day ? 'active_link' : '') %>
<% end %>
```

Obviously, you'll need to tweak that code some to work in your app - you haven't shown enough code for me to write a working code solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$('a.active_link').click(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('active_link');
});
```

I'm no expert of ruby, but this works if your link is rendered as

```
<a id='link' class='active_link'></a>
```

Comment: is your id on the anchor unique? For a while I made the mistake of having the same id on identical elements...the binding of the click was picking up just one of the things I had with that id. if you want to get just one, use a unique id, if you want to get more than one of the same conceptual thing, use an "id css class"...that is, one with no real css definition backing it. I usually distinguish those from real css classes by appending "-id" at the end.

Comment: As jaydel says id must be unique. I try to rewrite my code, try it

Comment: Can you post the html as is outputted to the browser?